# Google Oauth give additional scope when app request login

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Our app uses google Oauth for app user to sign in. We only request 3 basic scopes: profile, email and openid. We didn't request contact scope. But when user sign it, it ask user to allow this app to see and download contacts. Any help?

Comment: Sure. We delete images and links.

Comment: hi, did you manage to figure this out?